# C# Time Format String being like this (7.00:00:00)

Tags: c#, telerik, string-formatting, timespan

I have problem about time format string, that's always show (.) if I input something, Eg(input :7 and enter), it will be like (7.00:00:00) and error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3jX6.png)

Below is my code:

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="To Hour" DataMemberBinding="{Binding ToHour, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat=\{0:hh\\:mm\\:ss\}}" TextAlignment="Center" IsSortable="True" Width="*"   />
```

Model :

```
private TimeSpan _toHour;
        public TimeSpan ToHour
        {
            get { return _toHour; }
            set
            {
                IsModified = (_toHour != value ? true : IsModified);
                SetProperty(ref _toHour, value);
                ValidateField(nameof(ToHour));
            }
        }
```

I expect something like, Eg: if I input 7 and enter then output is 07:00:00

But the actual output is : 7.00:00:00

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: can you  show in your code how toHour variable looks like

Comment: what happens if you change it to this -> `StringFormat={0:hh:mm:ss}`

Comment: @MethodMan that's not works

Comment: @varnit this is my toHour variable :  private TimeSpan _toHour;
        public TimeSpan ToHour
        {
            get { return _toHour; }
            set
            {
                IsModified = (_toHour != value ? true : IsModified);
                SetProperty(ref _toHour, value);
                ValidateField(nameof(ToHour));
            }
        }

Comment: @PutriOkta I want to ask you which dotnet version you are using and why you have this initial trailing slash \{0:hh\\:mm\\:ss\}}

Comment: also this link provides you with details of how can you format the timespan https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings

Comment: @PutriOkta let me know if the above link helps

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, it can be handled in the model side (validation, etc, omitted):

```
private TimeSpan _toHour = TimeSpan.Zero;
public string ToHour
{
    get => _toHour.ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss");
    set
    {

        _toHour = value.Contains(":") ? TimeSpan.Parse(value) : TimeSpan.ParseExact(value, "%h", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ToHour));
    }
}
```

And remove string format from xaml:

```
DataMemberBinding="{Binding ToHour, Mode=TwoWay}"
```